# Can I force git branch --contains <tag> to not print the asterisk?

Tags: git

I'd rather not have to filter git's output but it looks like I may have to. Before I do, I want to make sure I'm not missing something.

After reading the output of `git branch --help` I see no option to add to my `git branch --no-color --contains <tag>` command that will make git print this:

```
<tag>
```

instead of this:

```
* <tag>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For scripting, use `git for-each-ref`.  It's meant for such purposes and hence is much more flexible and directly useful (and won't misbehave for other users if they have curious configurations set).

Unfortunately, unless you have Git version 2.7.0 or higher, your `for-each-ref` command does not implement `--contains`.  In that case you are stuck with `git branch --contains` and post-processing.  Piping to `cut -c3-` will do the trick.